how to integrate a function that has been rotated using a 2D rotation matrix
I'm faced with a problem that I can't solve. I had an ordinary logarithmic function that I rotated by some angle using the usual rotation matrix, but now I need to find the area under the graph of this function using integration on some segment.  Due to the fact that now it is impossible to separate variables in the equation relative to the equal sign, it is unclear how to integrate them. Is there any way to do this?
UPD:
I had a function:
$$y=ln(0.6|x|)+7$$
I applied the rotation matrix and transformed the expression as follows:
$$\begin{array}{l}x'\rightarrow x\cos\theta - y\sin\theta, \\y' \rightarrow + x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta.\end{array}$$
I got it for my equation:
$$(x\cdot\sin{(a)}+y\cdot\cos{(a)})=\ln{(0.6|(x\cdot\cos{(a)}+y\cdot\sin{(a)}|})+7$$
The purple curve is the original equation, the blue one is the rotated one:
enter image description here
Now, within these boundaries, I need to integrate the expression to get the area under the curve. I can't do this.

From what you wrote here, it is not clear what is your problem. Maybe showing an example would help.

Could you please add more details for better clarification? I believe we need more to go on to be of assistance. What have you tried? And how will this benefit not just yourself but others as well? I hope I'm not being rude but we need to ensure you follow said rules as well. Both of my posts got closed over this and I don't want the same to happen to you.

@Hume2
Thanks for the answers, I added information to make it better understood

suppose instead of a log, you had a simple line starting at the origin, could you solve it then?

@user619894
If it were a straight line, then the rotation matrix would not change its shape, it would just change direction, and in the case of a straight line it is easy to find the integral, but I did not understand what to do with such and more complex functions

rotation is a rigid transformation, so the area between the curve and a flat base is unchanged under rotationx up to the boundary of the region

So you start with the purple curve on $\approx[-12.25,-2]$, rotate it to get the blue curve, and you want to find the area under blue on the same domain? You can theoretically solve for $y$ as a function of $x$ then integrate as usual. Despite the hairiness, it turns out to have a "simple" antiderivative, judging by Mathematica's quick evaluation, but then again I'm not very familiar with Lambert's $W$ functionl

@user170231
Yes, it was in the old coordinate system that I wanted to find the area. I was more interested not in the end result that wolfram found, but in the method by which it could be found.

Well, you can strike the area under the curve which you need to calculate and then rotate the area together with the curve until it reaches the original (purple) curve again. This new area is very similar to the area under the purple curve except that you need to add and remove some triangles. However, you need to figure out the desired endpoints and those will be hard to calculate. You can do it either numerically or maybe using some advanced functions like Lambert's W.

I suppose you want the area under the blue curve in the figure.
Find the exact bounds of the part of the original function that you rotate to get the blue curve.
This is different from the purple curve you plotted: the left and right bounds will be different.
The endpoints of the curve you want have to rotate to the endpoints of the blue curve.
Integrate the original function between these bounds.
Now when you rotate the region you just integrated, you will have a region that has the correct curve along part of its boundary.
The rest of the boundary will consist of line segments.
This isn’t the region you want, but you can make it into region you want by removing or adding triangles along the straight edges.
Find those triangles and their areas.
Then you can add or subtract areas as needed to get your result.

Thank you. This will help specifically in this case, when there is a convenient grid, but I was more interested in the general analytical approach (does it exist at all?). More often we have to deal not with such simple functions, but with more complicated ones, for example, rotating superellipses, so I wonder if there is an analytical approach to solving such problems, not numerical.

@VazgenFeodorov This answer is analytical, not numerical, as long as you can find the two endpoints of your curve analytically. If you cannot even evaluate the rotated function at a point, integration will be difficult as well.
